# Xss sanitization in java

Tags: java, encoding, xss

I have a code piece to sanitize string symbols '<' and '>' for XSS attacks. Do you see any point in the snippet below where someone can break the code for these two symbols. I know XSS has lot more to sanitize and there are standard libraries. But do we expect any failures/breakage for the snippet below? Thinking from encoding/character set point of view also. Please have a look and suggest.

We can use replace also but this is already written code and I have to break it.

```
String next=""; //this will be a html get request param

final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < next.length(); ++i) {
  final char ch = next.charAt(i);

  if (ch == '<') {
    sb.append("&lt;");
  } else if (ch == '>') {
    sb.append("&gt;");
  } else {
    sb.append(ch);
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the context. But I am sure this code is NOT secure.

Comment: This kind of replace might break multi-byte characters (i.e. ones that do not fit to UTF-16).

Answer (score 4):

One possible attack would be:

```
&#0000060
```

This sign is also a **<** and need to be replace.

In fact I would suggest ***NOT*** to write the replacement yourself. Use [ESAPE by OWASP](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/) or [commons-lang from apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Comment: Well, in HTML, isn't &#0000060; just the same as &lt;?

Comment: I would still rather use esapi or something similar than coming up with my own implementation. Why reinvent the wheel, others have done it, and probably better.

Comment: @davida. Don't get it. Iv you make a char compare **< != &#0000060**

Comment: @Scorpio Yes, thats, why I added the links to esapi and commons-lang. **Don't** write it yourself. **Use** a library for this.

Comment: @davida. &#0000060 is treated as &lt; and hence not parsed as an html character.

Comment: Indeed, so it is not a possible attack and does not need to be replaced , does it? Btw. I fully agree with using a good existing library for this. Antisamy did a good job for me a while ago.